# unable to take screenshot

Tags: settings, release-loki, elementary-website, screenshot

I'm unable to take screenshots using the print screen button , and when i tried changing the settings also noticed you can't assign single key for the same , this used to work perfectly in freya .
p.s i had to take the picture from a external device  [image: as soon as i try to assign a key to take the screen shot the got disabled]

Comment: Although this question was made first, I'm voting to close it since the other one has more details.

Comment: See https://bugs.launchpad.net/screenshot-tool/+bug/1622224

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work for me either. I do not know if it is a bug or desired behaviour. Best thing to do would be to open up a bug report. This will bring the issue to elementary OS's team attention.

Meanwhile you can use the internal screenshot app of elementary OS:
Open the applications menu on the top left side of the screen and type screenshot. You can then choose to make a picture of the whole screen or port of it.